# Display latest comments (global) with replies on a page

Tags: pages, comments

Trying to display the latest 50 comments (global, from all the posts) on a page (page.php)

I am using this code:

```
  <?php $comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=50&type=comment&hierarchical=threaded');
      foreach($comments as $comment) :?>
      <?php $post = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID, 'OBJECT'); ?>
      <li>  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID);?>#comment-<?php echo($comment->comment_ID);?>">
         <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
          </a> 
<?php echo($comment->comment_content);?> 
      </li> <br/>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

It works fine, it shows the comments, but it doesn't show comment replies - I want to show replies too

```
`hierarchical=threaded`
```

should do the trick, but it doesn't. maybe because `The parameter is ignored (forced to false) when $fields is 'ids' or 'counts'`
But I don't know how to fix that

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with array method, using reply post type with its parent.

```
<?php
$args = array(
   'post_type'           => 'reply',
   'status'              => 'approve',        
   'post_parent'         => $postID,                   
   'posts_per_page'      => 50,                        
   'orderby'             => 'date',                        
   'order'               => 'ASC',                         
   'hierarchical'        => true,
   'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,                          
);

foreach(get_comments($args) as $comment) :?>
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure how to use this. If I integrate it into my code, it will only display a link to the current page. I need to display global comments (sitewide) not just current page

Comment: Just replace this with line 1 and 2 from your code

Comment: If I do that, it displays nothing

Comment: Try then replacing:
`'post_type' => 'reply'`
width: 
`'type' => 'comment'`